# console.log(!status) in global scope producing unexpected result

Tags: javascript, console.log

Ran into an interesting issue.  I was working on trying to toggle a boolean that was assigned to a variable.  It wasn't working and eventually I tried this code.

```
var status = false;
console.log(!status);
```

I expected it to provide `true` in the console, but instead I got `false`.  I figured that javascript would run the code inside the parenthesis first to find it's value and then console.log the value.  Could you please explain why I am not getting a `true` value in the console?

Comment: That's interesting in IE I got `true` but in chrome and firefox I get false

Comment: yeah i get true for other variables but false when status is used

Comment: `window.status` exists already. My guess is there is a conflict.

Comment: yeah i guess that may be

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)

Comment: elclanrs is right.  Tried it with a different variable name and it is working now.  I didn't know there was a window.status.  Good to know

Comment: Whatever the value you assign `window.status` with, it gets converted into string, therefore `!status` → `!"false"` → true.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) already exists (it is used to get/set the text of the browser's status bar) and when a value is assigned to it, it is converted to a string. If you do `console.log( status );` you will see that `status` has the string value `"false"`, which causes you to see the output `false`, since you effectively have `!"false"` and `"false"` is a truthy value in JavaScript.

If you do the same thing inside a function you'll get the expected output:

```
(function ( ) {
  var status = false;
  console.log(!status); // true
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)

```js
var statu = false;
console.log(!statu);
```

window.status exists already. so you can't use status variable .

Answer (score 1):

See the below screenshot which says that status is a property in window. 
So this directly refers to the window.status. 
It is not advisable to **reuse** certain variables and properties that are having **default meaning**(reminding about **keywords** in oops languages)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the type for `status` like this:

```
typeof status
```

The output will be: `"string"`.

Note that `false` and `"false"` are not same.

When you define:

```
var status = false; //which is actually "false"
```

That's why you are not getting `true`.

Answer (score -2):

```
(function ( ) {
  var status = false;
  console.log(!status);
})();
```

This will give you expected output.

"**status**" is a **predefined name of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties**. It is better avoid the identifiers as names of JavaScript variables. If you are using it outside the  function then it means you want to implement any other thing by status value.

Comment: But why? Explain your answer

Comment: I have edited my answer and explained @StephanBijzitter

Comment: No, it's not a *reserved word*. If it was, you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi FYI: Please look [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm). You can see the list of reserved words.

Comment: @BharatJain Yes. It's not in that list of reserved words. It's in the list of "*identifiers to avoid as names of JavaScript variables*".